# Wordpress primary domain

Tags: wordpress, dns

I've got a question regarding wordpress and multiple domains. I've got two domains (.cz and .com), both pointing to the same folder. The .com domain automatically redirects to the .cz domain. I would like to change this so that the .cz domain  redirects to the .com domain. I thought this can by done in my webhosting interface, however, tech support told me that I have to change it in wordpress. Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> General and update the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).

You should also set up 301 redirects to send the .com to .cz (and probably non-www to www, or vice-versa on both domains).

Do some Google searching, or search on here for tons of resources on how to do that.